# Vaadin override column ordering for Button inside Table

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin

I've made a Vaadin table which contains (apart from Strings) a button (with a link style and description) and it works great.

Only 1 problem: I can't sort the column! I've been trying to find a way to override the normal sorting of the column so it will take my Button's value and then sort it from A-Z or Z-A. I guess the default is just a toString of the field but I don't know for sure.

Example:

The table column (as where it's generated):

> table.addContainerProperty(Translator.translate("column.message"), Button.class, null);

...

> ```
>             Button messageButton = prepareButton(result);
>             resultComponent.getTable().addItem(new Object[] {
>                     messageButton,
>                     result.getPortlet(),
>                     result.getSsn(),
>                     result.getSam(),
>                     result.getDate()
>             }, itemId++);
> ```

Any way I can override the sorting? Or write my own sorting class or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/286792).  To sum it up, you can either extend the component (in this case the Vaadin button) and have the subclass implement Comparable or you can use an ItemSorter.